# rxjs: make transformations, not mappings

Tags: rxjs

I need to make transformations on subscription elements. So, I'm using transformation instead of mappings because I need to change a field object value of each feed. My subscription is:

```
this.subscription$ = this.store$
      .select(fromRoot.getSubscriptionEntities)
      .filter(subscription => subscription.status == 'active')
      .takeUntil(this.componentDestroyed$);
```

So, I need to:

```
foreach subscription
  subscription.periodEnd = subscription.periodEnd * 1000
```

Where should I do this? I've tried to do it into a `do()`, nevertheless all fields are read-only.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you trying to modify a "_foreign_" object?

Comment: From now on, it's mine.

Comment: ... the question was more intended like: What are you trying to accomplish with adding random attributes to classes you did not create yourself?

Comment: The ojects I'm receiving are containing values in seconds. I need to get them in millisecons.

Comment: Okay I think I'm lost now, but what you are referring to as `subscription` is actually the `data` that is received from the store, is that correct? If this is the case, please do __not__ call it `subscription` because the actual `subscription` and the received `data` are two completely different things. It's very easy to confuse your _"subscription"_ with an actual `rxjs-subscription`

Comment: Second question: All your data-objects are `read-only`, is that correct? - Third question: Is the data just being displayed or what are you doing with the `periodEnd`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a map and immutability ?

```
this.store$
  .select(fromRoot.getSubscriptionEntities)
  .filter(subscription => subscription.status == 'active')
  .map(subscription => ({
    ...subscription,
    periodEnd: subscription.periodEnd * 1000
  }))
  .takeUntil(this.componentDestroyed$);
```

*PS : you don't need to keep a subscription for your observable as you have takeUntil ;)*